# Moment handling daylight savings time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I need to manage dst with momentjs.
At fe I receive datetime (like 2022-04-05T10:59:13.640683) from be, I want to determine if I'm in dst to display the right dateTime.
If I'm in daylight savings time I want to add 1h.

I'm doing this with:

`const receivedDate = moment(dateTimeFormBe).format()`

`moment(dateTimeFormBe).isDST() ? receivedDate.add(1,'hour') : receivedDate`

It works but I want to generalize it. It only works if I'm in Italy, I want that it works everywhere.
Someone could help me?

Comment: You should never need to manually add an hour. As long as timezones are clear, `moment`/Javascript's `Date` will handle all that without you needing to do anything. Can you provide a clearer example of the values involved and the expected result?

Comment: Are you using Moment Timezone already? https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: Also it looks like you are abusing a ternary here

Comment: Also, your assumption that DST always shifts clocks forward by 1 hour is wrong: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should use [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to manage your timezones, which [does have DST baked in](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) as long as you use the `.format()` method

```js
var date = new Date();
var zone = 'Europe/Paris';
var dateZone = moment.tz(date, zone).format();
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
moment(date).add(moment().utcOffset(), 'm').format('DD-MM-YYYY -h:mm:ss');
```

This works perfectly fine for me. It converts utc time to local time by adding/subtracting utc offset time while catering to DST